# Defining an operator with given properties

Tags: function-construction, operators, attributes

In symbolic derivations with Mathematica, one often needs to define an operator with some desired properties, which will be used to stand for a general function or transform.

For example, I would like to define a linear operator `myOp[f[x, t]]`, which has the following basic properties:

1. Linearity: `myOp[a1*f1[x ,t] + a2*f2[x, t]] == a1*myOp[f1[x, t]] + a2*myOp[f2[x, t]]` with `a1` and `a2` being constant;
2. Commutation with linear differential operators: `myOp[D[f[x, t], {x, n}]] == D[myOp[ f[x,t] ], {x, n}]`;
3. Inversion: `myOp[ myOp[ f[x, t] ] ] == -f[x, t]`,

such that Mathematica can symbolically evaluate and simplify expressions substituted in. By the way, what necessary and/or useful *attributes* and/or *conditions* should also be given to the customized operator?

Comment: There have been multiple questions on this site regarding defining an operator with specified characteristics. See for example the "Related" list to the right. Have you perused those already? They may give you a jump start.

Comment: @MarcoB i read a number of related posts, but cannot figure out a proper definition on the property of commutation with linear differential operators **without** the chain rule applied on `f[x,t]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the following would work:

```
ClearAll[myOp]

myOp[Times[a_., myOp[b_]]] := -a b
myOp[Plus[a_, b_]] := myOp[a] + myOp[b]
myOp[a_ f_[x_, t_]] := a myOp[f[x, t]]
myOp[D[f_[x_, t_], {x_, n_}]] := Derivative[n, 0][myOp[f[a x, t]]][x, t]
```

For instance:

```
myOp[4 f[u, p] + 3 g[3 e, f]]
```

> `4 myOp[f[u, p]] + 3 myOp[g[3 e, f]]`

```
myOp@myOp[4 f[u, p] + 3 g[3 e, f]]
```

> `-4 f[u, p] - 3 g[3 e, f]`

```
myOp[D[f[x, t], {x, 2}]]
```

> `Derivative[2, 0][myOp[f[a x, t]]][x, t]`

(Thanks to [evanb for suggesting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193040/defining-an-operator-with-given-properties/193065#comment502689_193065) `a_.` within `Times`)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will read the related posts. The property of commutation with differential operators works in an improper way. `myOp[D[f[x, t], {x, 1}]]` is expected to give `Derivative[1, 0][myOp[f[x, t]]][x, t]`. That is, no chain rule, just interchange the operators.

Comment: @jsxs I guess we can define it that way already, using `Derivative` explicitly, instead of `D`. See if the amended code works better.

Comment: You probably want `Times[a_., myOp[b_]]` to let a default to 1.  Also, `Plus[a_, b__] := myOp[a] + myOp[Plus[b]]`

Comment: @evanb Your first point about the optional default argument in `Times` is very good, thank you! It saves one definition (changing answer now). On the other hand, it seems to me that your second case is already handled by the `myOp[Plus[a_, b_]]` definition, which gets applied recursively.

Comment: Hmm!  Very curious!  I know in previous similar applications I have found that kind of rule necessary.  I wonder what the difference was.

Comment: Thank you for the help! @MarcoB @evanb. By testing, i found the property of commutation with differential operators still works in an improper way: for `p[x, t] = myOp[D[f[x, t], x]] - D[h[x, t], {x, 2}];` `D[p[x, t], {x, 2}]` is expected to give `Derivative[3, 0][myOp[f[x, t]]][x, t]-Derivative[4, 0][h][x,t]`. However,  i saw chain rule applied on `myOp` again. Btw, is there a redundant `a` on the RHS of last line of the `myOp` definition? Thanks a lot!